# merge two dataframe with unequal and duplicate index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a empty dataframe with a datetime index like this:

```
>>> idx_df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2020/1/1, 2020/1/1, 2020/1/2, 2020/1/2, 2020/1/3, 2020/1/3, 2020/1/3, 2020/1/3, 2020/1/3, 2020/1/4, 2020/1/4, 2020/1/4, 2020/1/5, 2020/1/5, 2020/1/5, 2020/1/5]
```

I want merge another dataframe(df2) with unequal index length and with some duplicate index value to this empty dataframe.

```
df2                        desire result    
             transin        date        transin
date                        2020/1/1    1.0 
2020/1/1      1.0           2020/1/1    
2020/1/2      1.0           2020/1/2    1.0 
2020/1/2      1.0           2020/1/2    1.0
2020/1/3      1.0           2020/1/3    1.0 
2020/1/3      1.0           2020/1/3    1.0 
2020/1/3      1.0           2020/1/3    1.0 
2020/1/3      1.0           2020/1/3    1.0 
2020/1/3      1.0           2020/1/3    1.0 
2020/1/4      5.0           2020/1/4    5.0 
2020/1/4      6.0           2020/1/4    6.0 
2020/1/5     10.0           2020/1/4    
2020/1/5     11.0           2020/1/5    10.0 
2020/1/5     13.0           2020/1/5    11.0 
2020/1/5     16.0           2020/1/5    13.0
```

but I have tried:

```
pd.merge(idx_df, df2,right_index=True,left_index=True)
idx_df.join(df2)
pd.concat([idx_df, df2],axis=1]
```

all of these method can not give me desire result, so what should I do?

Comment: How does it not give you the expected result (what is the expected result?)? Can you provide your inputs and DataFrame constructors?

Comment: Hi, I upload my data(2 csv file) but I can't edit my thread today, the donwload link is :https://xfl.jp/weZBee, you can use pd.read_csv('df2.csv').set_index(date) to obtain the df2, and pd.read_csv('idxdf.csv') to obtain idx_df. thank you. And when I use pd.concat or merge or join, I got different prompts all saying it cannot be merged because of duplicate indexes, or cannot be merged horizontally(axis =1)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `reindex`

```
out = df2.reindex(idx_df.index)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I got a error when I reindex df2 as your mentioned, "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis".